# Recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Imagine a store. There are only three items available for purchase, and they cost $2$ dollars, $3$ dollars, and $5$ dollars respectively. Customers can only buy one item at a time.

a) Write a recurrence relation called $T_n$ which determines the number of the different ways to spend $n$ dollars at that store. Be sure to include all necessary base cases.

b) Compute the value of $T_{10}$.

So I don't understand how to come up with the relation $T_n=T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}+T_{n-5}$.

Comment: You could look into using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 0):

Hint. As regards a) the [(homogeneous linear) recurrence (of order $5$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) is: for $n\geq 5$, 
$$T_n=T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}+T_{n-5}.$$
In fact, with $n$ dollars, the last item costs $2$ dollars (when you have already spent $n-2$), $3$ dollars (when you have  already spent $n-3$) or $5$ dollars (when you have  already spent $n-5$).

The initial conditions are $T_1=0$, $T_2=1$, $T_3=1$, $T_4=0$, $T_5=?$.

Are you able to find $T_{10}$?

Answer (score 0):

The way to find the recurrence is to say that to spend $n$ dollars, you must have bought some items, then buy the last one.  You could either have already spent $n-5$ and then buy a $5$ item, or have already spent $n-3$, or have already spent $n-2$.  The ways to spend $n$ is the sum of the last three because they are distinct, which gives the recurrence you are looking for.

The point of the "you can only buy one item at a time" is that the order matters.  Buying $2+5$ is counted as different from buying $5+2$.